# app crash when i click sign in buttom

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

here is my my signupactivity & main activity and their xml

```
            public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                protected EditText mUsername;
                protected EditText mPassword;
                protected EditText mEmail;
                protected Button nbutton;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
                mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamefield);
                mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtextfield);
                mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtextfield);
                nbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signbutton);
                nbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view){
                        // Retrieve the text entered from the EditText
                        String usernametxt = mUsername.getText().toString();
                        String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                        String email= mEmail.getText().toString();
                        // Force user to fill up the form
                        if (usernametxt.equals("") && password.equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Please complete the sign up form",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                            // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage

                            ParseUser newUser =  new ParseUser();
                            newUser.setUsername(usernametxt);
                            newUser.setPassword(password);
                            newUser.setEmail(email);
                            newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    //SUCESS
                                    if (e!= null){

                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this);
                                        builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()).setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                        dialog.show();
                                    }
                                    else {


                                        Intent intent= new Intent(SignupActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                    }

                            });
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
```

it was suppose to get the information abt users and go to main activity from signupactivity.the app crashes when it get in put from users and press sign in...

here is the xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.josephvarkey996gmail.test1.SignupActivity" >

        <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/usernamefield"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
            android:hint="@string/username_hint"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/passwordtextfield"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/usernamefield"
            android:hint="@string/password_hint"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/emailtextfield"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:layout_below="@+id/passwordtextfield"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/signup_hint"
            android:id="@+id/signbutton"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    here is the main activity code

        package com.josephvarkey996gmail.test1;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;

        import com.parse.Parse;
        import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
        import com.parse.ParseUser;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
                Parse.initialize(this, "XFigOgliUYKi9h5RanLfLkuKU14AG2f2NFQXADKI", "sMQBPkhZV5b74MEGpP3PdQ6eePWo5Y9O8lRcQvBP");
                ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());


                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                if(currentUser==null) {
                    navigatetologin();
                }
                if(currentUser!=null)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG ,currentUser.getUsername());
                }
                // Enable Local Datastore.


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }



            private void navigatetologin() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

mainactivity xml

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity" >

            <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

android manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.josephvarkey996gmail.test1" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".SignupActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_signup" >
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".LoginActivity"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat of your exception?

Comment: Where is your logcat

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you until u post your logcat. As I don't have enough reputation to comment, I am writing this in answer.

Most common reason I saw people getting this error is:
They copy -paste this line from another class

```
R.id.usernamefield
```

So it will try to run the usernamefield of their other class which is not present here(note: eclipse will automatically import so they didn't get compilation errors). So to resolve your error you should delete the import and write proper R.id.xyz

But this is only shot in the dark until we see your logcat.